# jqGrid setRowData method doesn't update hidden rows

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid's `filterToolbar` method to let users quick search/filter the grid data. I'm using `loadonce: true` and `datatype: local` as my grid configs. I have a drop-down (select) filter type for one of my columns, which works fine.

Problem is when i try to update a row (using `setRowData`) that is not visible (because the filter/search result is hiding them), the row doesn't get updated when I reshow them by clearing the filter.

Any suggestions? I've tried triggering the `reloadGrid` event too, no luck.

Cheers

### Update 1 - Reproducing the problem:

Here's how to reproduce the problem, using jqGrid's official demos:

## Step 1

Browse to the jqGrid's demo page, and open the demo named 'Toolbar search' under 'New in version 3.7'

## Step 2

In the demo grid, filter by the code column with the value 575878 so that only the first row is shown on the grid.

## Step 3

Bring up the javascript console and update a row that's not currently visible, in this example update row 2:
`jQuery("#toolbar").jqGrid('setRowData',2,{item_id:2,item:'blargh',item_cd:12345678});`

## Step 4

Unhide all the rows by clearing the filter value, and see that row 2 has not been updated!

Anything I'm doing wrong here? Possible workarounds?

Comment: You should include in your question the JavaScript code which you use and the JSON data returned from the server. After that other will be able to reproduce your problem. In general `setRowData` work with hidden data too.

Comment: @Oleg I've update the question with steps to reproduce the problem, and seems like setRowData doesn't work with hidden rows. Any other way to update these hidden rows? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand how the grid are build. Grid can contain hidden columns, but **no hidden rows**. If one filter grid the full grid body will be removed and only the filtered rows will be inserted.

The method `setRowData` can be used to modify any row of the grid, but you can't modify something which is not present in the grid.

If you use local grid (`datatype: 'local'`) then the data which you save in the grid will be saved in two internal jqGrid parameters `data` and `_index`. So you should modify the `data` object. To fill grid with modified `data` you need call `.trigger("reloadGrid")`.

So if you want modify columns `item_id`, `item` and `item_cd` of the grid's data for the rowid=2 you can do the following steps.

1) Get references to the internal jqGrid parameters `data` and `_index`:

```
var $myGrid = jQuery("#toolbar"),
    data = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data'),
    index = $myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
```

2) Get reference to the object which represent the rowid which you need:

```
var rowId = '2',
    itemIndex = index[rowId],
    rowItem = data[itemIndex];
```

3) Modify the data item like you as need:

```
rowItem.item_id = 2;
rowItem.item = 'blargh';
rowItem.item_cd = 12345678;
```

4) Refresh grid contain (if needed) by reloading the grid

```
$myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');
```

Comment: Hi @Oleg do you have a more complete example of this? I cannot get local cell data updates to persist page to page, when I page back to the updated page it seems lost. These are set: `loadonce:true` `datatype:local` etc. Thx