# jqGrid's addRowData hangs for large number of records

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, grid

jqGrid's `addRowData(idColumnName, array, direction, position)` takes an array of rows and inserts them into the current page of the grid, ignoring any pagination settings. So if an array contains 3,000 rows, all 3,000 rows are inserted into the current page.

That throws an "unresponsive script" error in most browsers.

What "tricks" can one use to insert a very large number of rows (i.e. 3,000) into jqGrid at a specific position and have it respect pagination settings?

Comment: Why not use paging? so you don't have to pull so many rows at once?

Comment: These rows are generated on the client, not the server, so server-side pagination is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of `addRowData` to update (or to add) large number of pages is the wrong way. jqGrid use internal `data` and `_index` options to hold the local data (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145342/315935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026210/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373813/315935) for example). So you can get *the reference* to internal `data` parameter with respect of `getGridParam`. Then you can update the array in any way. You should additionally place the indexes of new added rows in `_index` or alternatively to call [refreshIndex](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L1080-1095) (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3348688/315935) for a code example) which rebuild the `_index`. In the last case you have to have full data source (`data`) which contains `id` property too. After all you should reload the grid (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935) about the parameters of `reloadGrid`) to display updated grid.

Comment: Many thanks! I now update the "data" parameter and reloaded the grid. In that way, jqGrid respects pagination settings.