# JQGrid: Get elements from different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with 24 elements, 10 elements by page.

When I run the following line, being on the 3rd page:

```
var idList = $(MyList).getDataIDs();
```

I can only get the 4 elements from the 3rd page.

How can I get the elements from the whole list?

I've tried:

```
$(MyList).jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

but I get:

```
[]
```

(related with [JQgrid data property returns [] on a grid with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954922/jqgrid-data-property-returns-on-a-grid-with-data))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you `datatype: "local"` or if you use remote data source (`datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`) **together** with `loadonce: true` then `data` and `_index` parameters will be filled. The option `data` is array of items. The option `_index` is an object which properties are id values of the loaded data. You can use `for` loop to iterate over all ids. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6417757/315935) or [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026210/315935) for more information. In some scenarios it would be practical to use `getLocalRow` method to access items from `data` array by id.