# JQgrid data property returns [] on a grid with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I try:

```
$(MyGrid).jqGrid('getGridParam');
```

On a grid with 24 elements, data has nothing.

Do you know under which conditions this might happen?

[image]

(related with [JQGrid: Get elements from different pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954250/jqgrid-get-elements-from-different-pages))

Comment: Are you loading the data dynamically? If so, it's not a parameter.

Comment: @Irvin, yes I am, that was it. Thank you!

Comment: LuisGouveia I simply edited the question, the thanks goes to @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padameter `data` hold **local** data of the grid. It will be not filled (stay empty array) if you use **remote source** (`datatype: "json"` or `datatype: "xml"`) without `loadonce: true` option. In the case jqGrid just fill the grid (HTML table) with the **page** of data returned from the server. In the case the server hold the data only and it is responsible for sorting, paging and filtering/searching of data.

If you have not a large dataset (less as a million or less as 10000 rows) then one have better performance typically by usage of `loadonce: true` option. In the case the server can just return sorted data with **all** items. jqGrid will display the first page of such data and will hold **all** data returned from the server in `data` and `_index` parameters. After the first loading jqGrid changes `datatype` to `"local"` and all later sorting, paging and searching/filtering of the data will be done without any communication with the server.